# Difference between "<pattern value=ABC\s*\d*" & "<pattern value=ABC\d*\d*" in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I dunno exactly but i think \s*\d* is something like "string + int" and \d*\d* is "int + int"
Any body with clarification.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

- `\d` matches a single digit (`0` - `9`)
- `\s` matches a whitespace character (space, tab, newline, ...)
- `*` matches zero or more versions of the previous item.

So `\d*` matches zero or more digits, and `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.

This means that `ABC\s*\d*` will match strings like `ABC 2345`, `ABC234` and `ABC`.

`ABC\d*\d*` is the same as `ABC\d*`.

See [this introduction to regular expressions in XSLT 2](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html) for more information.

Comment: One minor clarification, \d matches all Unicode digits, not only 0-9. If you want ASCII digits only, use [0-9].

Comment: @Michael Kay: Thanks for the correction. The tutorial i linked to says it's equivalent to `[0-9]`, but the [XSLT 2.0 Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#regular-expressions) quotes the [XML Schema 2 Standard regex definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs) which includes Unicode treatment.